# box plot does not show outliers

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is my function to create box plot. But it does not show the outliers. any help?

```
def box_plot_draw (data, box_colors): 
        #plt.style.use('Solarize_Light2')
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()#figsize=(10, 6))
        fig.canvas.set_window_title('A Boxplot Example')
        fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.075, right=0.95, top=0.9, bottom=0.25) # 


    bp = ax.boxplot(data, notch=0, sym='+', vert=1, whis=1.5)  
    plt.setp(bp['boxes'], color='black')                       
    plt.setp(bp['whiskers'], color='black')
    plt.setp(bp['fliers'], color='red', marker='+')
    box_colors = box_colors


    ax.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5) #what is which?
    ax.set_axisbelow(True)


    #setting the tile for distribution
    ax.set_title('Comparison of the duration of time for two Distributions')
    ax.set_xlabel('Distribution')
    ax.set_ylabel('Value')
```

You can test the code using this data.

```
np.random.seed(10)
collectn_1 = np.random.normal(100, 10, 200)
collectn_2 = np.random.normal(80, 30, 200)


## combine these different collections into a list    
data_to_plot = [collectn_1, collectn_2]
box_colors = ['black', 'green']    

box_plot_draw (data_to_plot, box_colors)
plt.show()
```

I am using the Jupyter notebook and I used styles for other functions. But I did not use any style for this function.

Comment: What is `box_colors` defined as?

Comment: @HS_nebula, show the color for box,

Comment: [This](https://imgur.com/a/0Mlo5Cp) is what I get. I can see the outliers with a `+` symbol. What is the problem?

Comment: @but for me does not show the outliers. Do you know how I can overwrite matplotlib style?